# My WebViewClient is refreshing in a loop

Tags: android, loops, webviewclient

I'm trying to load a web in a webview, but when the page is loaded, the webview carry on refreshing the view in a loop. How I can avoid this?

My code to load the page is the next:

In the **onCreateView**:

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(pathto.get_register_service());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new RegisterWebViewClient());
        webView.invalidate();
```

The **custom** class of the **WebViewClient**:

```
   private class RegisterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_error_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_error_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reloading page in `onPageFinished` event with `view.loadUrl(url);`

`onPageFinished` is triggered when page has finished loading and you should not reload the page inside that event or you will end up in endless loop.

Comment: The bad habit of the copy&paste. Thank you, this is the answer.